# Acrobat Pro DC and WinEdt

Tags: winedt, acrobat

I recently installed Acrobat Pro DC.  Now, everytime I have to manually close my pdf document before I run WinEdt.  If my document is open, and I run WinEdt, the file PDFCLoseDoc.edt opens up and highlights line 52

```
DDEOpen("%$('PDF-View')","%$('Acro-DDE_Service');","%$('Acro-DDE_Topic');");
```

If I also try to do a search now from WinEdt to PDF, the PDF Search.edt opens up and highlights  line 107

```
DDEOpen("%$('PDF-View');","%$('Acro-DDE_Service');","%$('Acro-DDE_Topic');");
```

and gives me the error:

[image]

How can I get WinEdt and Acrobat Pro DC to corporate as before when I had Acrobat 8?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are _compiling_ a document with Acrobat Reader open, you'll get an error. If you are just _editing_ the document, you won't need Acrobat open anyway (just after you compile, to see the results). Or maybe use another editor/viewer.

Comment: But in the past when I had Acrobat 8 installed, even if I had the document open, WinEdt automatically closed the pdf and then compiled the document.

Comment: Then, that's a very specific WinEdt Acrobat Pro DC problem. Use another editor/viewer, and your problems will go away.

Comment: You should better ask this on the winedt mailing lists. The macros winedt use to close the pdf files before the compilation are rather complicated and often need to be adapted to a new reader version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### UPDATE

WinEdt 9.1 build 20150713 now supports Adobe DC.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Every couple of years the Adobe staff changes the way DDE works and informations written on Windows registry by their products...

To let WinEdt work with Acrobat DC (Acrobat or Reader), you have to open the Options Interface, go to "Advanced Configuration" -> "PDF Macros" and double-click on "Adobe Blues".

[image]

A local copy of the file `Adobe.edt` gets opened. In this file, substitute the lines

```
  IfNum("%!1","%!2",">",>
   !`>
       LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");|);>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");|);>
    `,>
   !`>
       LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");|);>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");|);>
    `);
```

with

```
  IfNum("%!1","%!2",">",>
   !`>
       LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");|);>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader','   ');");|);>
       LetReg(4,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!4','','<>',!|LetReg(3,"DC");|);>
    `,>
   !`>
       LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKLM','SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");|);>
       IfStr('%!3','','=',!|LetReg(3,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat','   ');");|);>
       LetReg(4,"%@('HKCU','SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\2015','   ');");>
       IfStr('%!4','','<>',!|LetReg(3,"DC");|);>
    `);
```

and the line

```
  IfOK(!'GetTag(0,3);GetTag(1,4);',!'LetReg(3,"99999");LetReg(4,".0")');
```

with the lines

```
  IfOK(!'GetTag(0,3);GetTag(1,4);');
  IfStr('%!3','DC','=',!|LetReg(3,"15");LetReg(4,".0");|);
```

At this point save the file and restart WinEdt.

These changes will be incorporated in the next build of WinEdt.

---

Anyway, Acrobat is not really the best PDF viewer to work with TeX & friends.

I suggest you to install [SumatraPDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) and use it for TeX interaction. Note that you can keep `.pdf` files to be opened with Acrobat when double-clicking on them and use SumatraPDF when working with `.tex` files.

To do that, choose "Options" -> "Execution Modes" -> "PDF Viewer". There, click on "Alternative Viewer 1" and then "Apply".

[image]

Comment: Although I don't use for TeXing, I have Adobe Reader DC and I can confirm that the patch works in this case.

Comment: It works for me as well.